# How to model a simple mouth

Tags: modeling, extrude

I am almost done modeling a Pokémon character. However, it's mouth is giving me headaches. I thought I could do something simple as seen in the Dinosaurs splash screen of Blender:
[image: Blender splash screen]

It looks like they inset the mouth and performed a bevel.

I'm not getting a clean inset of my character's mouth and the vertices right under the lip are giving me issues with beveling.
[image]

What's the best way to achieve a clean inset and bevel?

[image]
(Note: Backup folder contains a model without my try with modeling the mouth)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to create a topology that follows the shapes of your head, something (roughly) like that (circular edges around the eyes, nose, mouth...). It will make the animation work better and also it makes thing easier if you need to add edges:

[image]